# Visual Studio Additional Include Paths?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on an existing Visual Studio 12 "Solution" from another team..

In one of its "project"s,, there's a header file that includes a file from another static library projecet..

So Lets say the solution structure looks something like this:

```
Project A (Static Library Project)
   \__ someFile.h

Project B (Static Library Project)
   \__ someLibrary.h
```

In **someFile.h,**

```
...
#include "someLibrary.h"
...
```

and this loads the library successfully.. BUT this is strange because the path to **someLibrary.h** is NOT SPECIFIED anywhere in Project A's settings!!

I've checked **Configuration Properties => VC++ Directories => Include Directories** but path to someLibrary.h is NOT specified here..

Since Project A is a static library with NO cpp files (has only header files), It does not have a **Configuration Properties => C++ => Additional Include Directory** Option at all... (It only has the **Librarian** option)

And of course **someLibrary.h** is not in the same directory as **someFile.h**.

Finally, in Project A's **Common Properties**, Project B is not referenced either...

So my question is : How the hell does someFile.h know where someLibrary.h is?

How is it including it??

Is there any other places in project settings/etc where additional include directory can be specified..?

**UPDATE:**

when I right click on the #include statement and click "Open Document 'someLibrary.h'",

I do see a following VS error box:

```
 File 'someLibrary.h' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths.
```

Nevertheless,, there is NO build error, and Project A uses someLibrary.h with no problem!!

Comment: Same happening with me. Projects uses library without any problem but when i hover on the ' #include "someLib.h" ' i get cannot open source file error.
You found some solution regarding this?